# Understanding Mongoose Schema better

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

*I am relatively new to the MongoDb world, coming from a MS Sql / Entity framework environment.*

I am excited about Mongo, because of:

> ***MongoDb's ability to dynamically change the shape of the class/table/collection at run time.***

Entity framework does not offer me that.

**Why is that so important?**

Because I would like to create a generic inventory app and have the product class/collection/table be dynamic ***for clients to add fields pertinent to their business that cannot be used by everyone***, eg. Vin Number, ISBN number, etc.

Now I have come to learn about Mongoose and how it offers a schema, which to me detracts from the flexibility of MongoDb described above.

I have read in a few sections that there is such an animal as mixed-schema, but that appears to be dynamic relative to the data type and not the collection of properties for the given class/collection/table.

**So this is my question:**

If I am looking at developing a generic class/collection /table that affords clients to shape it to include whatever fields/properties they want that pertain to their business, dynamically, should I abandon the whole notion of mongoose?

Comment: With such a dynamic schema, Mongoose's utility is pretty limited.  What features of Mongoose are you looking to use?

Comment: That is just it. I have read up on Mongoose and I see no real benefit of it over MongoDb. Hence the reason I ask the question here. I mean if I am going to strongly type my properties, and by way of that, pre-define what my properties are, aren't I back to a relational database of sorts again? Aren't I losing the whole benefit of dynamic properties/fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found a benefit today as to where a Schema may be warranted:**

Allow me to preface though and say I still thoroughly am excited about the whole idea that Mongo allows a collection to be reshaped at run time in circumstances where I may need ti to be. As mentioned above, a perfect example would be an Inventory app where I would want each client to add respective fields that pertain to their business as opposed to other clients, such as a Car dealership needing a VIN Number field, or a Book store needing a ISBN Number field.

Mongo will allow me to create one generic table and let the client shape it according to his own wishes for his own database at run time - SWEET!

But I discovered today where a schema would be appropo:

If in another table that will not be 're-shapeable', say a user table, I can create a Schema for pre-determined fields and make them required, as such:

```
 var dbUserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   title: {type:String, required:'{PATH} is required!'},
   FullName: {
       FirstName: {type: String, required: '{PATH} is required!'},
       LastName: {type: String, required: '{PATH} is required!'}
   }
 });
```

By having the respective first-name and last-name required from the schema, the database will not add any records for a user if they are not both included in the insert.

So, I guess one gets the best of both worlds: Tables that can be re-shaped and thru a schema, tables that can be rigid.

Comment: No application is truly schemaless, there is always one. Might as well define it up front. This is why PostgreSQL is a good option because you get super performant SQL and the addition of schemaless JSONB columns. I suppose I might see if Mongoose has aded better validation.